# How to check if app is in top charts

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

How can I check in iTunes Connect if my app(s) is in any top lists/charts in the App Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [appannie.com](http://appannie.com) : *Sales. Reviews. Rankings. 24/7. Global.*.

You can monitor all your AppStore and Mac AppStore applications. Ranks and reviews all over the world AppStores.

And it's free.

Comment: Link provided resends to another web.